# "Cannot gather stats! Warning!"

Tags: magento2

I am trying to solve a backend warning which is shown whilst trying to edit any configurable or simple product in my Magento 2 backend. The warning is:

> Cannot gather stats! Warning!
>   stat(): stat failed for /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/pub/media/catalog/product/t/a/sample_image.jpg

I've seen [the discussion here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/2db5aa15722307fb6ad703627933224f5f74bbe3) with regard to this problem to attempt to resolve this warning. However I don't want to change my core files. Is there any other option to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please run below sql code

```
SET @file = '/t/a/sample_image.jpg';
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery WHERE value = @file;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE value = @file;
COMMIT;
```